# Absolute value in ARel (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel, relational-algebra

I need to do some absolute values in ARel. Basically need to understand how to execute this line (in Relational Algebra) using ARel:

Assume P is a table with columns value1 and value2:

```
Project((|p.value1 - 10| + |p.value2 - 10|) as match) P
```

Not sure if this is possible with ARel yet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you are stuck with the num.abs method for now:  http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html#M001355

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking it's basically that for now. I've ended up using ActiveRecord with order and using ABS from sqlite. It's working for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off doing this is SQL:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.abs_values
    connection.select_values('SELECT abs(value1-10), abs(value2-10) FROM projects')
  end
end
```